# How to properly sort elements with changing values of elements by Stream API

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, refactoring

I have a list of items that contain the value of the position. The problem is that for different reasons there may be gaps between position values. Therefore, we must constantly eliminate them.

For example, if we have an element with the values of position: 1000, 10, 500, then we must first sort these elements, and then assign them values starting from zero, that is, it should be 0, 1, 2

Code:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
        books.add(Book.of(1L, 1000L));
        books.add(Book.of(2L, 10L));
        books.add(Book.of(3L, 500L));

        List<Book> resultList = getSortedByPositionWithoutSpaces(books);

        Book first = resultList.get(0);
        Book second = resultList.get(1);
        Book third = resultList.get(2);

        if (!first.getPosition().equals(0L)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Invalid first element position");
        }
        if (!second.getPosition().equals(1L)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Invalid second element position");
        }
        if (!third.getPosition().equals(2L)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Invalid third element position");
        }
    }

    // How to change this method using only streams?
    public static List<Book> getSortedByPositionWithoutSpaces(List<Book> books) {
        List<Book> sortedList = books.stream()
                .map(e -> Book.of(e.getId(), e.getPosition()))
                .sorted(comparing(Book::getPosition))
                .collect(toList());

        List<Book> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
        long i = 0L;
        for (Book entityForChange : sortedList) {
            resultList.add(Book.of(entityForChange.getId(), i));
            i++;
        }
        return resultList;
    }
}

final class Book {
    private final Long id;
    private final Long position;

    private Book(Long id, Long position) {
        this.id = id;
        this.position = position;
    }

    public static Book of(Long id, Long position) {
        return new Book(id, position);
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Long getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Book{");
        sb.append("id=").append(id);
        sb.append(", position='").append(position).append('\'');
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Book book = (Book) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, book.id) &&
                Objects.equals(position, book.position);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, position);
    }
}
```

I don't like how the method is implemented getSortedByPositionWithoutSpaces().

is it possible to somehow implement this conversion only through the Stream API? that is, remove the For loop

Comment: PSA: `for` loops are not an evil construct that should be destroyed wherever they are found, and the Streams API is not a silver bullet that magically makes things better just because you used it.

Comment: @JonK thx! yes of course, I just think you can write a method more concisely

Comment: But at the same time, don't get too hung up on whether or not something can be made *more* concise if it's already concise enough to ensure it's easily maintainable. If it takes you two hours to refactor a for loop to use the Streams API, but it's in a file that almost never changes, you're probably wasting your time in the grand scheme of things. I'm not saying "*don't do that*", but it's worth asking yourself "*does it **really** matter if it's left as-is?*"

Comment: Replace `toList()` with `toCollection(ArrayList::new)`, to ensure a mutable `List`, then, perform the change in-place: `IntStream.range(0, sortedList.size()) .forEach(i -> sortedList.set(i, Book.of(sortedList.get(i).getId(), i));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea is to use `AtomicLong` and map your Book objects once again after sorting:

```
public static List<Book> getSortedByPositionWithoutSpaces(List<Book> books) {
    final AtomicLong i = new AtomicLong();
    List<Book> sortedList = books.stream()
            .map(e -> Book.of(e.getId(), e.getPosition()))
            .sorted(comparing(Book::getPosition))
            .map(e -> Book.of(e.getId(), i.getAndIncrement()))
            .collect(toList());        
    return sortedList;
}
```

Comment: Is it safe if I use parallel stream?

Comment: Not need to `.map(e -> Book.of(e.getId(), e.getPosition()))`

Comment: The operation does not work in parallel, as it uses a function with a side effect. While the `AtomicLong` is thread safe, incrementing it in a `map` function creates a dependency on the evaluation order. Such a dependency and parallel processing don’t go well together.

Comment: @Holger Thanks for the explanation. I have removed the incorrect comment.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply iterate over an `IntStream` corresponding to the size of the `sortedList` and apply the indices directly the book ids:

Something like this (didn't test it):

```
IntStream.range(0, sortedList.size()).forEach(i -> sortedList.get(i).setPosition(new Long(i)));
```

Comment: poor implementation because side effect is used

Comment: True. My main point was using IntStream. Just replace the forEach-part by `.mapToObj(i -> Book.of(sortedList.get(i).id, new Long(i)))` to get rid of the side effect.